# How do you determine if Command ID came from context menu of a CTreeView or the main menu?

Tags: winapi, mfc, contextmenu

I have a `CTreeView` where certain commands on menus act upon the selected item.

When you right click and get the context menu, you can get the `HITEM` and save it to a member variable to know which item to act on when the user selects the option from the menu.

**NOTE**: I'm using `BCGControlBar Pro` built-in context menu support:

```
GetContextMenuManager()->AddMenu(_T("My menu"), IDR_CONTEXT_MENU);
// ...
theApp.ShowPopupMenu(menuid, point, this);
```

However, when you also want the main menu to act on the selected item you need to know to get the selected `HITEM`.

I can't set the context menu member variable to NULL after the menu closes since it may be null when the handler for the command is run.

How is this normally handled in MFC/Win32 when you want to keep the same Command ID for both context menu and main menu?

TIA!!

Comment: You could save the selected item when the `WM_INITMENU` message is received?

Comment: in what problem call `TreeView_GetSelection` in both case ?

Comment: MFC doesn't distinguish them. Wherever it comes from, the main menu, a popup menu, toolbar or accelerator, you just have one `ON_COMMAND` handler. Even the `WM_COMMAND` message distinguishes only between  menus and accelerators (and well, controls), not between main and popup menus. Check if you can apply the `MNS_NOTIFYBYPOS` to the menu, which will cause it to send `WM_MENUCOMMAND` messages instead, and catch this message in MFC. Otherwise... somehow use different IDs, eg add an offset to the popup menus' IDs before displayed and process them separately in your code.

Comment: Why do you need to save the selected tree item at all? Just query the tree for its selected item at the time you need it. Then you can have as many menu handlers as you need all act on the tree as needed. I don't see the problem here.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  I didn't want to have to change the selection.

Comment: @user3161924 I do not understand what you are describing. Please [edit] your question to clarify the actual problem in more detail.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You can right-click on a tree item that isn't the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Comments and From what I've seen, the answer is you can't.  Instead you must do one of the following:

Option 1) When the right click occurs, change the TreeView selection so that the `OnCommandXXX()`function uses the selected tree item.

Option 2) Track the `HTREEITEM` in a member variable before the context menu is shown, Use `CContextMenuManager::TrackPopupMenu()` instead of `CContextMenuManager::ShowPopupMenu()`, use the return value to find the menu item, `SendMessage()` the command, use the member variable to determine the `HTREEITEM` if it's not `NULL` otherwise the selected tree item, before exiting the function that handled the context menu and sent the command, reset the member variable to `NULL`.